# Filter The Records In The PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, microsoft-fabric

I have three tables for the PowerBI report

1. `'table1'` Which is having below columns

- id1
- name1

2. `'table2'` Which is having below columns

- id2
- name2

3. `'table3'` which is having below columns

- id3
- name3
- tempid

I have given dropdowns/slicers for `'table1'[id1]` & `'table2'[id2]`.
I want to get the records from the `'table3'` where `'tempid' = [Selected value of 'id2']` OR `'tempid' = [Selected value of 'id3']`.

How to do that in the PowerBI.

Comment: You should be able to do this by setting up relationships. In power bi desktop, go to the Model View to the far left. Then in the ribbon, click Manage Relationships and setup relationships between the tables/columns as you've specified. I.e table3.tempid = table2.id2 and so fourth.
Hope this helps you in the right direction

Comment: @wenzzzel, Thanks for the reply. Actually I have 'table1', 'table2', 'table3',...,'table6'. and the 'table7' is having the 'tempid' column. The slicers of table 1 to 6 is filled up based on the selections. Suppose if we select value from the tabl1 dropdown, Then based on the selection of it, The dropdowns of other will be bounded. To achieve this I have already given the relationship with each other tables. If I am trying to add the relationship, Then I am getting ambiguity error now.